# Post function on NodeJs Deployed on aws returns Error:502

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, paypal, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am currently implementing a server that handles PayPal API calls from client and comunicates with PayPal's services in order to get token and create users in braintree.

The deployment went out well regarding elastic beanstalk. When i call the token method through the router i get the token and a success. The problem stands when i try to create a new braintree customer i get a cryptic  502 error. Any idea why? I am using the standard nginx setup from AIM listening on port 80. This is not a duplicate since the other similar questions did not resolved my issue.

Using nginx 1.8.0

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var http = require('http');
var braintree = require('braintree');

var gateway = braintree.connect({
                            environment: braintree.Environment.Sandbox,
                            merchantId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                            publicKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                            privateKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                            });

router.get('/', function(req,res) {
       res.send('Iam a tree, a brain tree');
       });

router.get('/token', function (req, res) {
       gateway.clientToken.generate(null, function (error, response) {
                                    res.json(response);
                                    });
       });

router.post('/createCustomer', function(req, res) {

var customer = req.body;
console.log(req.body);
       gateway.customer.create({
                               firstName: customer.firstName,
                               lastName: customer.lastName,
                               company: customer.company,
                               email: customer.email,
                               phone: customer.phone,
                               fax: customer.fax,
                               website: customer.website
                               }, function (err, result) {
                               res.json(err,result);
                               });
       });

module.exports = router;
```

**main.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('static-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var routes = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(favicon());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);

/// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
var err = new Error('Not Found');
err.status = 404;
next(err);
});


// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: err
    });
});
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
res.status(err.status || 500);
res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
});
});

module.exports = app;
```

And finally my **www** file

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var debug = require('debug')('test');
var app = require('../main.js');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8081);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my question since i found the issue of the problem. The root of the problem was in the "/createCustomer", removing err from

```
res.json(err,result);
```

and changing it to

```
res.json(result);
```

Also i am not creating a customer with options(name, last name) just an empty one. To wrap it up the "/createCustomer" router function looks like this now.

```
/* Get Creates a new customer with the given params */
router.post('/createCustomer', function(req, res) {

  var customer = req.body;
  console.log(req.body);

  gateway.customer.create({}, function(err, result) {
    res.json(result);
  });
});
```

This is a bit strange since the first version of the function was copied from the Braintree documentation about Node server setup. Anyway for the moment this workaround allows to create a customer link it with my current user on a custom Parse server and edit its properties later.